# Div height 100% excluding header

Tags: html, css

Ok so I know this topic has many questions, but I still haven't been able to figure exactly how to make this work.   [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794860/css-100-height-header-with-static-height) is close to the problem, but its not working for me.

I want my page to have 100% height.  Inside this page is a static header of height 40px, and then content that takes the remaining height (100% - 40px).

**HTML:**

```
<body>
     <div id="page">
          <div id="header">
             header
          </div>
          <div id="content">
             content
          </div>
      </div>
 </body>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body
{
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0px;
}

#page
{
    min-height: 100%;      
}

#header
{
    height: 40px;
} 

#content
{
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 40px;        
}
```

This is an explanation of the code:

- I added `position: absolute` to content because otherwise it would not take up 100% of its container `#page` for some reason
- Then the problem was that it exceeds the boundaries of the page, which is why I added top: 0.
- Then the contents of `#content` overlaps with the header so I added `padding-top: 40px`
- Now the `#content` exceeds the boundaries of the page again

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/94JNZ/1/

```
#content
{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: This works but what can be done when the data exceeds the page and there is a scroll bar?

Comment: You can add `overflow:auto` to #content

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article about this problem. [CSS 100% height problem](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html)

You can see the example page has a perfect 100% layout what header and footer.
It uses relative position and not absolute.

Comment: I don't believe the content div in that example is actually stretched to use the remaining space.  Rather I believe it is Header -> Content -> Remaining Space -> Footer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `box-sizing` property for this

Check this:

### http://jsfiddle.net/Gn8zN/1/

**Another simple & best solution**

Check this:

### http://jsfiddle.net/B8J2H/

Comment: please include the answer in the post, in case external sites goes down

Answer (score 0):

Use **flex:1;**

```css
html, body
{
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0px;
}

#page
{
    min-height: 100%;      
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header
{
display: flex;
    height: 40px;
    background-color:red;
} 

#content
{
    display: flex;
  flex: 1;    
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
     <div id="page">
          <div id="header">
             header
          </div>
          <div id="content">
             content
          </div>
      </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score -3):

Just script it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function contentSize()
{
    document.getElementById('content').style.height=(window.availHeight-40)+"px";
}
onload=contentSize;
onresize=contentSize;
<script>
```