# Actual <DIV> size is bigger than expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well, to start with, here is the HTML template:

```
<div id="content">
    <header>...</header>
    <div id="pages">
        <div class="page">...</div>
        <div class="page">...</div>
        <div class="page">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the pages are placed below the header and they become visible by JS code (initially they are not).

It all works, the problem is that the page is sized to the height of screen and ignores the header height. So you can see a scrollbar going outwards the screen borders.

```
+--------------------------+   ---------
| HEADER                   |      |
|                          |      |
*--------------------------*      |
| PAGE                     |      |
| content                  |      | - SCREEN SIZE
| content                 #|      |
| content                 #|      |
| content                 #|      |
+--------------------------+   ---------
| content                 #|
| content                 #|     # is scrollbar
*--------------------------*
```

Even if the page doesn't have any content, the page is still the full screen size.

CSS:

```
*, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
    background-color: #fdc162;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    height: auto;
}

.page {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Why does this happen, and how can I get rid of it without JS?

Comment: try defining `min-height: 100px; ` or `max-height: 100px; ` in your header css something along those lines i think is what you're after?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. But I can see in your CSS you have given .page {height:100%}, in this context you are telling .page to be 100% of the screen

Comment: height:auto is better way , or set min-height:10000000000000px;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Div height 100% excluding header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172102/div-height-100-excluding-header)

Comment: OMG, how could I miss it. I was searching for hours but didnt  seen it. Thank you guys and sorry :/

min-height: 100% works well.

Comment: Hmm, not really well, but i got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

in your class `.page` instead of using `height:100%` and `width:100%` use `auto`.