# Css content height 100% is scrollig page

Tags: html, css

I have a `header` and `content` divs in my html page. I want to set an image or map in my content that will be 100% but does not appear scroll bar. Fit the height of page with header and content.

```
<div class="head">
      Header
</div>
<div class="content">
     <img class="image" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/daisy_pollen_flower_220533.jpg"/>
</div>
```

And my CSS is like this.

```
html, body {height: 100%}
.head{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.content{
  border: 1px solid blue;
height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.image{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Most likely a duplicate to [how to make DIV height 100% between header and footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228280), [Div height 100% excluding header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172102) or [Get div to take up 100% body height, minus fixed-height header and footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021573)

Answer (score 2):

100% + 1px border is more than 100%.

To fix that, remove the border or use

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

Additionally, your `.content` has a height of 100%. That is 100% of the client height of its parent. It's not the *remaining* height, and it doesn't take other children into account. So the `.head` is added to that height, and together they will be 100% + 100px + 4px (for borders) of the total page height leasing to a scrolling range of 104px.

The vertical scrollbar in return will consume some of the horizontal space, so you might get a horizontal scrollbar as well because of that.

You could consider using `calc` to solve this by making the height:

```
.content {
  height: calc(100% - 104px);
}
```